# When does state update in React

Tags: reactjs

I am just learning React and I was doing the tutorial : https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

In it, we are suppose to create a function that calculate the winner of the tic-tac-toe and we pass to it the list of the squares' contents. I update this list each time a square is clicked. However, I noticed that when I use `this.setState` to set the squares list of my Board object and then try to have it with `this.state.squares` I do not get the active state but the previous one.

Like if I add an X in the first square, it will be in `this.state.squares` at the next move.

Here is the code, I use  :

```
handleClick(square){
    let squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[square] = this.state.playing;
    console.log(squares);
    this.setState({squares: squares});
    if(this.state.playing == 'X'){
      this.state.playing = 'O';
    }
    else{
      this.state.playing = 'X';
    }    
    this.state.winner = calculateWinner(this.state.squares); #If I do that I get the previous state
    this.state.winner = calculateWinner(squares); #If I do that I get the current state 
  }
```

Why does it do that ?

Comment: `setState` is async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

`setState` is an asynchronous method which effectively means that all other code in your `handleClick` function will execute before `this.state.squares` is mutated.

But there's another issue in your code too -- you're also trying to modify state directly:

```
if(this.state.playing == 'X'){
  this.state.playing = 'O';
}
else{
  this.state.playing = 'X';
```

Modifying `this.state` directly will not re-render your component.

To resolve these issues, you may use a `setState` callback:

```
this.setState({squares: squares}, () => {

    if(this.state.playing == 'X'){
      this.setState({"playing":"O"});
    }
    else{
      this.setState({"playing":"X"});
    }
    // I'm assuming that `calculateWinner` does not depend on this.state.playing   
    this.setState({"winner":calculateWinner(this.state.squares));
});
```

The `setState` callback is only invoked once the `this.state.squares` mutation has occurred -- ensuring that `this.state.squares` is updated before you invoke `calculateWinner`.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous but it can take a callback:

```
this.setState(
  { squares: squares },
  () => console.log("whatever")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a quick walkthrough of the different methods of the

> LifeCycle

of a component.
You must have good understanding of the lifecylce methods to code in react.
It will tell you "

> When does state update in React

"

> Methods in Mounting Phase:

It begins when an instance of a component is created and  when it gets rendered into the DOM.

1.`constructor(props)` - it is called when the component is first initialized. This method is only called once.
2.`componentWillMount()` - it is called when a component is about to mount.
3.`render()` -it is called when a component is rendered.
4.`componentDidMount()` - it is called when a component has finished mounting.

> Methods in Updating Phase:

It begins when a component's properties or state changes.

1.`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` - it is called when a component has updated and is receiving new props.
2.`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` -it is called after receiving props and is about to update. If this method returns false, componentWillUpdate(), render(), and componentDidUpdate() will not execute.
3.`componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` -it is called when a component is about to be updated.
4.`render()` - called when a component is rerendered.
5.`componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` -it is called when a component has finished updating.

> Methods in Unmounting Phase:

It begins when a component is being removed from the DOM.

1.`componentWillUnmount()` - it iscalled immediately before a component unmounts.